# Android - Animate VideoView or MediaController

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-view, android-video-player

I want to animate the displaying and hiding of a `VideoView`.

My `View` is wrapped in a `MediaController`.

My code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
```

I tried to animate with this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.my_anim);
videoview.startAnimation(anim);
```

I also tried to animate the `MediaController` but no luck so far.

I found just un- or not quite answered posts around the net.

Does anybody has an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Ron

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm also stuck in kinda same situation when I want to bring videoView into screen with animation but the MediaController simply shows up intact in a place without any animation.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Look at the date of that question... sorry, man.

Comment: No worries. @Ron